# 'MissingMethodException' in F# project

Tags: f#, missingmethodexception

My unit test project has 'InternalsVisibleTo' access to the project I'm trying to test, but even though it compiles fine, when I run my tests, it fails with a `MissingMethodException`.

Comment: [Don't unit test internals.](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2015/09/22/unit-testing-internals)

Answer (score 1):

This bug is particularly nasty in that it only happens for some times. The one that was tripping me up was the F# `list` type, if I changed the signature to array, it was fine.

I eventually found the problem/solution [here](http://blog.wezeku.com/2013/11/08/missingmethodexception-when-migrating-from-f-3-0-to-f-3-1/), which was that my test project was referencing FSharp.Core version 4.3.1.0, and the target project was 4.3.0.0

Setting them both to 4.3.1.0 fixed the problem for me.